# geolocalização quero pegar dados do java script e passar para um hidden

Tags: php

veja o codigo a baixo queria pegar as 2 infomações em passar para uma variavel ou para um input.

```
<p  id="demo">Clique no botão para receber sua localização em Latitude e Longitude:</p>
<button onchange="getLocation()" onclick="getLocation()">Clique Aqui</button>

<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="O seu navegador não suporta Geolocalização.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
  x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar o desejado, você deve colocar 2 inputs hidden no seu html e depois adicionar o código abaixo dentro da função `showPosition` dessa maneira:

```
<p  id="demo">Clique no botão para receber sua localização em Latitude e Longitude:</p>
<button onchange="getLocation()" onclick="getLocation()">Clique Aqui</button>

<input type="hidden" id="latitude">
<input type="hidden" id="longitude">

<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
{
    if (navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }else{x.innerHTML="O seu navegador não suporta Geolocalização.";}
}
function showPosition(position)
{
    x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 

    document.getElementById('latitude').value = position.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById('longitude').value = position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```

Comment: mais os 2 inputs estao sem value nao retorna nada.

Comment: @RomarioOliveira mesmo depois de passar pela função no javascript seus inputs tem value vazio??? Você tem certeza de que o script está chegando dentro do `showPosition`?

Comment: sim estou passando em Metho POST

Comment: resolvido funcionou obrigado deste ja

Comment: Tranquilo @RooOliveira feliz em ter ajudado, se puder marcar a resposta como respota correta :)

Answer (score 0):

Eu sugiro que você use o `document.getElementById`, você cria um input com o tipo hidden e com algum id, por exemplo:

```
<input type="hidden" id="latitude" name="latitude">
<input type="hidden" id="longitude" name="longitude">
```

Agora, depois de usar sua função, você seta o dado pra dentro desse input, seria algo assim:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    // essa successFunction vai receber os dados da posição
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
} 

function successFunction(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById("latitude").value = lat;
    document.getElementById("longitude").value = lng;
}
```

Agora é só colocar esses inputs dentro de um form e enviar para o PHP. Sugiro usar um [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) ou [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) da vida para enviar para o PHP